# Filter in js that are less than < 50 characters long

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom-events

I am working on simple js function... 
`GetShortMessages` takes an array of objects with '.message' properties and returns an array of messages that are less than < 50 characters long.
Providing my code below in the fiddle.. 
Basically I am trying to learn a filter:

```
function filteredMessages(messages){
        return messages.length < 50;
}

function getShortMessages(messages) {
// SOLUTION GOES HERE
    var filtered = messages.filter(filteredMessages);
    return filtered;
}

module.exports = getShortMessages
```

When I verify I am getting the below error

Verifying "Basic: Filter":

```
ACTUAL                             EXPECTED
------                             --------
"[]"                            != "[ 'Ea occaecat adipisicing anim voluptate mollit.', "
""                              != "  'Incididunt mollit dolore commodo ipsum.', "
null                            != "  'Veniam irure non Lorem enim nostrud.', "
null                            != "  'Excepteur commodo nulla consequat nostrud mollit.', "
null                            != "  'Eiusmod enim sunt aliqua veniam mollit.', "
null                            != "  'Sunt nisi deserunt labore ut ipsum nostrud.', "
null                            != "  'Ad officia proident irure sit.', "
null                            != "  'Ex laborum eu elit irure velit anim commodo.', "
null                            != "  'Eu laboris adipisicing non ea.', "
null                            != "  'Adipisicing cillum officia et nostrud.', "
null                            != "  'Pariatur laboris officia eiusmod Lorem.', "
null                            != "  'Aliqua esse reprehenderit proident deserunt.', "
null                            != "  'Nulla commodo enim sint excepteur duis ea.', "
null                            != "  'Aliqua elit culpa consequat consectetur.', "
null                            != "  'Mollit dolore nostrud officia dolore.', "
null                            != "  'Amet laboris labore labore minim id.', "
null                            != "  'Mollit aute labore dolor nisi irure dolor.', "
null                            != "  'Laborum velit mollit anim cupidatat ad mollit.', "
null                            != "  'Sit do pariatur pariatur velit ipsum.', "
null                            != "  'Adipisicing proident minim minim minim.', "
null                            != "  'Labore quis sit ut sit id.', "
null                            != "  'Labore eu nisi deserunt ea occaecat consequat.', "
null                            != "  'Exercitation culpa nostrud incididunt aliquip.', "
null                            != "  'Eu sunt amet do ea sunt adipisicing nostrud.', "
null                            != "  'Incididunt magna id qui cillum do.' ]"
null                            != ""
# FAIL
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `filteredMessages` function needs to accept an argument as the `Array.filter` method applies a callback to each element passing that element as an argument to the supplied callback.

```
function filteredMessages(message){
    return message.length < 50;
}
```

You don't actually have to write any separate functions for this and could use an anonymous function instead:

```
messages.filter(function(message){
   return message.length < 50;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...when I run the programe I get empty array but when I verify it its failing...update dmy code and error...

Comment: I'm not sure how you are calling this, but it works fine. Open the console and run this updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kf36sbd/2/

Comment: thanks for your reply...I think I am using an additional function...is it possible to achieve without creating additional functionals * Do not use any for/while loops or Array#forEach.
* Do not create any unecessary functions e.g. helpers.

Comment: M: is it possible to achieve with this function alone function getShortMessages(messages) {
// SOLUTION GOES HERE
    var filtered = messages.filter(filteredMessages);
    return filtered;
}

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to accept `message` attribute:

```
function filteredMessages(){
    return messages.length < 50;
}
```

Change function to

```
function filteredMessages(message){
    return message.length < 50;
}
```

Comment: @mrthyl: thanks for your reply...when I run the programe I get empty array but when I verify it its failing...update dmy code and error...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you have an array of object with "message" property and you don't have an array of strings. This should be your solution.
In the filter function you have to check the message property of the passed object

```js
var messages = [];
messages.push({message: 'text 1'});
messages.push({message: 'text 2 is long, very long, more long than 50 chracters, you know '});
messages.push({message: 'text 3'});


function filteredMessages(obj){
        return obj.message.length < 50;
}

function getShortMessages(messages) {
    var filtered = messages.filter(filteredMessages);
    return filtered;
}
var module = {};
module.exports = getShortMessages;

var filtered = module.exports(messages);

for(var i in filtered){
    console.log(filtered[i].message);
}
```